# How to create combo graph with 4 measure series?

Tags: amcharts, iccube-reporting

I have a graph I want to reproduce using IcCube reporting, (see example below)

[image]

I tried using AMChart combo chart type but without succes because there are 4 series of measures, I can do it when there are only 2 but did not succes with 4.

Could someone provide a working example ?

Comment: Asking for a working example without posting what you've done is frowned upon on SO. Can you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your AmCharts attempt and explain what about it that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is to use the standard Serial Chart. With the latest reporting version you can set-up axis that can be used by more than one measure.

This is how to do it:

1. Create 4 Graphs, a graph for each measure
2. Set the first two to Column, the 3rd and 4th to line
3. Create 2 Value axis
4. Set the 1st and 2nd measure to use the 1st Axis, the 3rd and 4th to the 2nd Axis.

[image: 2nd solution]

In Live Demo / How To / Stackoverflow - Combo graph with 4 measures - 2nd solution
That is it. All the rest is embellishment.

Comment: This is so the latest, it's not yet public ;-)

Comment: Looks exactly what I'm looking for, will test it as soon as I get this release. :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Create a combo Chart Create a MDX with 3 measures ( One for the bar
  values for both Nb 2016 and Nb 2017 -> Nb, one for 2016 Valorisation
  and the last one for 2017 Valorisation )
- Add 3  Graph Configuration (two first one already exists)
- Set the values of the 3 graphs to  Nb,
  2016 Val, 2017 Val and the chart types to column, line, line.
- Use for the 3 graphs the default Value Axis.

This should do it[image]

In Live Demo / How To / Stackoverflow - Combo graph with 4 measure series

Comment: tried your report, but the values showed for the lines (2016 Val, 2017 Val) are the ones of "Nb", as it is on screen above.

Comment: yes, indeed, it's for the sake of the example to show it works.

Comment: Ok, my fault, I did not see you used Amount for all the measures.  I Tried with Count measure iso the Amount one for the last 2 measures and this is more clear.  Thanks ic3!

Comment: But, still cannot move the 2 last measures on a new axis on the right.